# rpy2 loading error with MacOS 13.5 and m1 chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpy2

I have the following error when trying to do `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` on Jupyter Notebook (Python).

Error:

> OSError: cannot load library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

I am using MacOS 13.5 and my Mac has m1 chip.

Any idea about the issue? How to use rpy2 in my environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by installing R-x86_64.pkg as well on my Mac.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).